# django-tables2 checkbox column name

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I've created my table output with django-tables2, but I want a specific name in the table column for the check-boxes.

How can I do that ?

Here is my class for the table drawing, I've modified the sequence of the columns so that my check-box is the first one.

```
class SimpleTable(tables.Table):
    amend = tables.CheckBoxColumn(verbose_name=('Amend'), accessor='pk')

    class Meta:
        model = SysimpReleaseTracker
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        listAttrs = list()
        listAttr = list()
        listAttrs = SysimpReleaseTracker._meta.fields

        listAttr.append('amend')
        for x in listAttrs:
            listAttr.append('%s' %x.name)
        sequence = listAttr
```

Comment: To make `amend` the first column, all you have to do is `sequence = ("amend", "...")`. Here's the doc for [sequence](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#Table.Meta.sequence)

Comment: The sequence is modified and all the existing columns are added directly from the model because there are more than 20 and also if someone will add a new column to the model, it will be displayed using the TABLE._meta.fields that it's inserted into the list.
My problem is with the check box column, that one doesn't have a name but a simple check-box in the header as well :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CheckBoxColumn` has it's own unique rendering for the header and so it will not show the `verbose_name` unlike all the other columns. You could subclass `CheckBoxColumn` to change it's behavior though.

```
class CheckBoxColumnWithName(tables.CheckBoxColumn):
    @property
    def header(self):
        return self.verbose_name

class SimpleTable(tables.Table):  
    amend = CheckBoxColumnWithName(verbose_name="Amend", accessor="pk")
```

Alternatively, you could use a `TemplateColumn`.

```
class SimpleTable(tables.Table):  
    amend = TemplateColumn('<input type="checkbox" value="{{ record.pk }}" />', verbose_name="Amend")
```